# Passar valor SQL pra uma variavel VB.Net?

Tags: sql, vb.net

Tenho este código que executa uma SQL:

```
strsql = "select Nome, Senha from users where Nome=@field1 and Senha=@field2"
objcmd = New Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strsql, objconn)
With objcmd
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", "valor1")
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", "valor2")

End With
objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
objdr = objcmd.ExecuteReader
If (objdr.Read()) Then
    MsgBox("Sucesso.")
Else
    MsgBox("Erro desconhecido.")
End If
objcmd.Dispose()
objdr.Close()
```

Eu quero saber, como eu posso pegar um valor, por exemplo o **Nome** e colocar em uma variável (*pegar o valor da coluna e passar para uma string*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para trazer essas informações utilize a classe [MySqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) setando a sua variável com o retorno do [MySqlCommand](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) `.ExecuteReader()` , *exemplo*:

```
strsql = "select Nome, Senha from users where Nome=@field1 and Senha=@field2"
objcmd = New Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(strsql, objconn)
With objcmd
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field1", "valor1")
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@field2", "valor2")
End With

Dim objdr As MySqlDataReader
objdr = objcmd.ExecuteReader

If (objdr.Read()) Then // se existe registro.
    Dim nome as string = objdr.GetString(0);
    Dim senha as string = objdr.GetString(1);
Else
    MsgBox("Erro desconhecido.")
End If
objcmd.Dispose()
objdr.Close()
```

O `objdr.GetString` retorna o valor da coluna por posicionamento de 0 até o número total de colunas, se for duas colunas igual está na `SQL`, é **0** para *Nome* e **1** para *Senha*, e assim por diante.

Vale lembrar que o tipo é muito importante para que não tenha problemas nas conversões, e os tipos de dados tem que ser correspondente ao tipo que está na colunas em suas tabelas de retorno, [o exemplo abaixo retirado do site do http://www.macoratti.net, mostra os tipos correlativos e seus respectivos acessos para banco de dados](http://www.macoratti.net/12/11/ado_mdes.htm) `SQL Server`:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| SQL Server       |.NET Framework | Acessor .NET Framework | SQLType          |
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| binary           | Byte[]        | GetBytes()             | GetSqlBinary()   |
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| bit              | Boolean       | GetBoolean()           | GetSqlBit()      |
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| char             | String Char[] | GetString() GetChars() | GetSqlString()   |
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| datetime         | DateTime      | GetDateTime()          | GetSqlDateTime() |
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| decimal          | Decimal       | GetDecimal()           | GetSqlDecimal()  |
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| float            | Double        | GetDouble()            | GetSqlDouble()   |
| -----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| image            | Byte[]        | GetBytes()             | GetSqlBinary()   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| int              | Int32         | GetInt32()             | GetSqlInt32()    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| money            | Decimal       | GetDecimal()           | GetSqlMoney()    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| nchar            | String Char[] | GetString() GetChars() | GetSqlString()   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ntext            | String Char[] | GetString() GetChars() | GetSqlString()   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| numeric          | Decimal       | GetDecimal()           | GetSqlDecimal()  |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| nvarchar         | String Char[] | GetString() GetChars() | GetSqlString()   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| real             | Single        | GetFloat()             | GetSqlSingle()   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| smalldatetime    | DateTime      | GetDateTime()          | GetSqlDateTime() |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| smallint         | Int16         | Int16                  | GetSqlInt16()    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| smallmoney       | Decimal       | GetDecimal()           | GetSqlDecimal()  |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| sql_variant      | Object        | GetValue()             | GetSqlValue()    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| text             | String Char[] | GetString() GetChars() | GetSqlString()   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| timestamp        | Byte[]        | GetBytes()             | GetSqlBinary()   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| tinyint          | Byte          | GetByte()              | GetSqlByte()     |  
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| uniqueidentifier | Guid          | GetGuid()              | GetSqlGuid()     |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| varbinary        | Byte[]        | GetBytes()             | GetSqlBinary()   |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| varchar          | String Char[] | GetString() GetChars() | GetSqlString()   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

<sub>Dísponível em: http://www.macoratti.net/12/11/ado_mdes.htm</sub>

***Referencias:***

- [4.1.2 The MySqlCommand Object](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html)
- [Método SqlDataReader.GetString (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [MySqlCommand().ExecuteReader().GetString() does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7061341/6797930)
- [Método DbDataReader.GetString (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método DbDataReader.Read ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ADO .NET - DataReader - Melhorando o Desempenho (C#)](http://www.macoratti.net/12/11/ado_mdes.htm)

Answer (score 2):

O método que você está utilizando para efetivamente executar as instruções SQL é o `ExecuteNonQuery()`. Se perceber na [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx), lá diz que esse método não retorna nenhuma linha. Ele é usado para fazer operações como `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DELETE` e esses que não retornam dados.  O retorno do método que você tem utilizado é o número de linhas afetadas pelo *script* e só.

Como o que você quer é retornar linhas do banco, usando o `SELECT`, tem que usar outro método. Esse será o [`ExecuteReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Dim reader = objcmd.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetInt32(0))
End While
```

No `reader.GetInt32(Integer)` é onde eu pego o valor de uma coluna numérica retornada pelo `SELECT` e manipulo de alguma forma. Nesse exemplo eu imprimi no console, mas você pode armazenar em uma variável. O argumento `0` é o índice da coluna.

No meu exemplo utilizei o `GetInt32(Integer)`, mas como você pode precisar de outros tipos, existem outros métodos como  `GetDouble`, `GetGuid`, `GetDecimal`, `GetString`, etc.

No exemplo

```
select Nome, Senha from users where Nome=@field1 and Senha=@field2
```

`Nome` seria o índice 0 e `Senha` o índice 1.

- [MSDN: "Como criar e executar uma instrução SQL que retorna linhas?"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fksx3b4f.aspx)